# How do I drush vset a number with decimals?

Tags: drush

> drush vset latest_version 6.34a
>
> latest_version was set to "6.34a"

So far so good.

> drush vset latest_version 6.34
>
> latest_version was set to 6.

Hmm...

> drush vset latest_version '6.34'
>
> latest_version was set to 6.
>
> drush vset latest_version "6.34"
>
> latest_version was set to 6.

Comment: What happens if you explicitly set the type to string?

Comment: Pretty sure this is a bug in `_drush_variable_format()`.  It uses is_numeric() instead of is int().  I would post in the issue queue.

Comment: @greg_1_anderson  That was quick :)  I was going to investigate this further when I got home from work, with the hopes of giving you a patch.

Comment: Wow, yeah that was quick. Not sure why assumed it wasn't a bug.

Answer (score 5):

Turns out that calling Drush as follows does the trick.

<-- language: lang-bsh -->

```
drush php-eval "variable_set('latest_version', '6.34');"
```

It also turns out that this is a bug, and that awesome [greg_1_anderson fixed it within hours of me asking the question](http://drupal.org/node/1982736).